# Webview implementation differences in different versions of Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am looking into rendering performance issues I am having in my web-based wrapper app on older devices, and I noticed something odd. When I try to search for answers about this, the answer seems to amount to "don't worry about it."

Looking at under "Settings > Developer Options > Webview implementation", I am seeing the following on different test devices:

Oppo AX5s on Android 8.1:

- Chrome 91.0.4472.120 has been selected
- Android System WebvView 69.0.3497.100 is "Disabled for user Owner"

Nokia 6.1 on Android 9

- Chrome 91.0.4472.120 has been selected
- Android System WebView 68.0.3440.91 is "Disabled for user Owner

Pixel 4 on Android 11

- Android System WebView 91.0.4472.120 has been selected
- No mention of Chrome at all (but Chrome is installed on the device)

I recall somewhere in my searching, that at some point in Android development, it was decided to disable the WebView, and implement it with Chrome for performance reasons. Is this actually true? Why is WebView disabled in these older Android versions? Did this state of affairs change again further down the track, by the time of Android 11, such that perhaps now both Chrome and WebView use the same code, and Chrome is implemented with a WebView?

Also, is there truly any performance impact between different implementations?

Comment: Related: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#webview

Comment: @MorrisonChang That's useful, but it doesn't explain why the WebView option is disabled (as in, not able to be selected) on these older devices.